# how to make insert into in select

Tags: postgresql

i want to use insert into in select like this :

```
INSERT INTO action_periodique (action_periodique_valeur_id, affaire_id , typetache_id , etattache_id , actionemail_id)
SELECT (
    INSERT INTO action_periodique_valeur (nom , debut_rappel , fin_rappel , freq_rappel , champ_id , affaire_id)
    SELECT nom , debut_rappel , fin_rappel , freq_rappel , champ_id , 430
    FROM action_periodique_valeur
    WHERE action_periodique.action_periodique_valeur_id = action_periodique_valeur.id
    RETURNING id ), 
430 , typetache_id , etattache_id , 
    (INSERT INTO actionemail ( copiecarbone , destinataires , expediteur , message , repondrea , sujet)
     SELECT copiecarbone , destinataires , expediteur , message , repondrea , sujet
     FROM actionemail
     WHERE action_periodique.actionemail_id = actionemail.id )
FROM action_periodique
where affaire_id = 170
```

it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You provided next to none information about what you are trying to do.

But it *seems* to me that you are looking for a data modifying CTE.

Something like this:

```
with c1 as (
    INSERT INTO action_periodique_valeur (nom , debut_rappel , fin_rappel , freq_rappel , champ_id , affaire_id)
    SELECT nom , debut_rappel , fin_rappel , freq_rappel , champ_id , 430
    FROM action_periodique_valeur
    WHERE action_periodique.action_periodique_valeur_id = action_periodique_valeur.id
    RETURNING id
, c2 as  (
  INSERT INTO actionemail ( copiecarbone , destinataires , expediteur , message , repondrea , sujet)
  SELECT copiecarbone , destinataires , expediteur , message , repondrea , sujet
  FROM actionemail
  WHERE action_periodique.actionemail_id = actionemail.id
  returning id
)
INSERT INTO action_periodique (action_periodique_valeur_id, affaire_id , typetache_id , etattache_id , actionemail_id)
SELECT (select id from c1),
       430, 
       typetache_id, 
       etattache_id , 
       (select id from c2)
FROM action_periodique
where affaire_id = 170;
```

If this is not what you want you need to be **way** more specific.

Comment: thank you , it's what i need , but i have this error.  ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT" 
LINE 2: INSERT INTO action_periodique_valeur (name, debut_rappel ...

Comment: @user3812865: what is your Postgres version?

Comment: postgresql 9.0 version

Comment: @user3812865: then my solution won't work. Writeable CTEs where introduced with 9.1 (as you didn't state your version I assumed you were using the current version). If you really need this you need to upgrade

Comment: I installed version 9.3 and I have this error again this 
ERROR: more than one returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: @user3812865 this means that the select in one of the CTEs returns more than one row. You need to decide how you deal with that in the final select. You can either use a `limit 1` in the sub-queries or do a join between `action_periodique` and the other results in order to insert more than one row. It's impossible to answer this without more detailed example data.

Comment: the idea is to have a recursion on the three blocks, the first insert into must insert a line in 'action_periodique_valeur' when the condition is fulfilled, and return the id of the new line, the same for the second insert into '. and insert into the third, add a new row in table 'action_periodique' by inserting the two resulting id of the first two sub queries. I want these three blocks are repeated as 'affaire_id = 170'

Comment: I understand that, but the error indicates that the *first* insert already inserts more than one row, not just one.